# TextField Right align text

Tags: java, html, wicket, textfield

In wicket textfield how can I align text and cursor to right of the textfield? For number input right alignment of the text is better in my opinion. What I want is to write text from right to left, usually it is in opposite.

Comment: This maybe more of an HTML question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either or both of these on your input element:

```
 align="right" 
 style="text-align: right"
```

Does the trick according to [here](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/541421-right-align-content-input-field) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167027/how-do-you-right-justify-text-in-an-html-textbox).