# Right Justifying text using a class

Tags: html

Referring to this [Stackoverflow accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167027/how-do-you-right-justify-text-in-an-html-textbox)

```
input {
    text-align:right;
}

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blah</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        input { text-align:right; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="2">
    </body>
</html>
```

This approach will right justify all text boxes. How do I use a class to separate the textboxes that I want right justified from those that I don't?

```
<STYLE>
        NumericInput
        {
            text-align:right;
        }
</STYLE>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtRndRbtAmt" runat="server" CssClass="NumericInput" Enabled="False" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
```

This doesn't work unless I enclose the textn a DIV and assign teh NumericInput class to teh DIV.

Is a DIV avoidable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class selector starts with `.` period symbol.

So It should be:

```
.NumericInput{
    text-align:right;
}
```

**OR You May Write:**

```
input.NumericInput{
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong selector. Use

```
.NumericInput {
  text-align:right;
}
```

(notice the dot)